# Runkit can't redefine static method

Tags: php, datetime, runkit

I have this class

```
class DateTimeHelper
{
    public static function getDateTimeNow()
    {
        return new \DateTime('now');
    }
}
```

And I want in tests redefine output to date that I want:

So I do:

```
    $r = runkit_method_redefine(
        DateTimeHelper::class,
        'getDateTimeNow',
        '',
        'return new \DateTime(\'2016-01-01\');',
        (RUNKIT_ACC_PUBLIC | RUNKIT_ACC_STATIC)
    );

    var_dump($r);
    var_dump(DateTimeHelper::getDateTimeNow());
```

But runkit always returns false. So method is not redefined I get current datetime and can't get more info about what is wrong.

Is there way to to get more information wht is wrong or am I doing something wrong?